# Where have I messed up getting audio to play in the app for my son?

Tags: arrays, swift, ipad

## Background

So for a couple weeks my son had a fantastic app that he loved, with some incredibly useful help from this community. He enjoyed it so much, I signed up for the developer account so I can update the app in-between times when I can be with him. The app has since stopped working. I'm hoping you will be generous with your knowledge and either point me in the right direction of the resource you trust for answers or can see what I'm doing wrong here and let me know. Thank you so much.

[image]

## Question

1. Why doesn't the audio play when the buttons are pressed? I get no errors or warning from the code, but it won't play a noise. The audio files plays perfectly fine in Xcode so they have not become corrupted.
2. The audio files are stored in an audio folder in the app bundle and are stored in "category" colors, numbers, letters, etc etc. for easy storage. I just want to confirm that there isn't a case sensitivity or an issue with nesting the files within folders.

[image]

3. Not as critical, but so I don't feel like I'm doing it the dumb way. How do I change sound option so I don't have the enumerate each audio file, but instead the app will automatically search for the file name based on the image name?
4. If there is a smarter way to going about doing this I would really appreciate hearing your input. There are so many resources. I'm going through Apple's books on swift and it's helping me create a much stronger (or any) foundation of knowledge, but any other suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Here is my code with only one category included.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

class SoundManager{
    static let instance = SoundManager()
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    enum SoundOption: String {
        //Aircraft
        case airliner
        case biplane
        case bomber
        case cargoplane
        case fighterjet
        case glider
        case hangglider
        case helicopter
        case hotairballoon
        case parachute
        case privatejet
        case rocket
        case seaplane
        case spaceshuttle
        case tiltrotor
        case zeppelin
    }
    
    func playsound(sound: SoundOption){
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: sound.rawValue, withExtension: ".m4a") else {return}
       
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            player?.play()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error playing sound. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

    
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedImageName: String?
    private func gridButton(imageName: String, sound: SoundManager.SoundOption) -> some View {
        Button {
            SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: sound)
            selectedImageName = imageName
        } label: {
            Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .frame(width: 140, height: 140)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("ACTION'S FAVORITE STUFF")
                .lineLimit(1)
                .padding(10)
                .font(.system(size: 500))
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .bold()
                .background(Color(red: 0.18 , green: 0.59 , blue: 0.65 ))
            HStack{
                ScrollView{
                    //Aircraft Start Here
                    Text("Aircraft")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                        .border(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.black/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                    Grid{
                        GridRow{
                            gridButton(imageName: "Airliner", sound: .airliner)
                            gridButton(imageName: "Bi-Plane", sound: .biplane)
                            gridButton(imageName: "Bomber", sound: .bomber)
                            gridButton(imageName: "Cargo Plane", sound: .cargoplane)
                        }
                        GridRow{
                            gridButton(imageName: "Fighter Jet", sound: .fighterjet)
                            gridButton(imageName: "Glider", sound: .glider)
                            gridButton(imageName: "Hang Glider", sound: .hangglider)
                            gridButton(imageName: "Helicopter", sound: .helicopter)
                        }
                        GridRow{
                            gridButton(imageName: "Hot Air Balloon", sound: .hotairballoon)
                            gridButton(imageName: "Parachute", sound: .parachute)
                            gridButton(imageName: "Private Jet", sound: .privatejet)
                            gridButton(imageName: "Rocket", sound: .rocket)
                        }
                        GridRow{
                            gridButton(imageName: "Seaplane", sound: .seaplane)
                            gridButton(imageName: "Space Shuttle", sound: .spaceshuttle)
                            gridButton(imageName: "Tilt Rotor", sound: .tiltrotor)
                            gridButton(imageName: "Zeppelin", sound: .zeppelin)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.red)
                LazyVStack{
                    if let selectedImageName = selectedImageName {
                        VStack {
                            Image(selectedImageName)
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .cornerRadius(15)
                            
                            Text(selectedImageName)
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Display a default image here
                        VStack{
                            Image("Elephant")
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .cornerRadius(15)
                            Text("My Family")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.blue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more details about what you code actually does at runtime. Use the debugger and step through the code in `playsound`. Update your question with what is actually happening. Does it get past the `guard`? Is `player` non-nil`?

Comment: Also, please keep your question narrowed to a single question. Focus this one on getting the sound to work. You can always ask another question at a later time.

Comment: So sound was working before, but now it's stopped? What exactly changed? You said, you signed up to a developer account for providing updates, so is the app now being loaded from TestFlight instead of by being connected to your computer? If so, try checking that the sound files are being included in the target bundle: in Xcode, inspect every sound file and make sure "target membership" is checked.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment. I think I got it solved. Thank you for sharing your knowledge and helping me get this thing working again.